# ASP.Net Core Razor Folder Routing with Parameter

Tags: c#, routes, razor-pages

I might going on a wild goose chase but I don't think I'm really understanding how to do what I want using the routing options in ASP.Net Core Razor Pages.

I have the following folder structure:

```
 Pages/
     Languages/
        Language/
            Index.cshtml
            Edit.cshtml
            Export.cshtml
            etc...
     Index.cshtml
```

Each of the pages under `Languages/Language` should have a `{langId}` parameter added to their route.

So far, I know that I specific for each of the files in that folder the `@page "..."` directive like so:

```cs
@page "/languages/{langId}/export"
...
```

What I would like to achieve is configuring Razor Pages to automatically assign such a route pattern for pages in that folder.

Something like this:

```cs
builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(o =>
    {
        o.Conventions.MapFolder("/Languages/Languages",
        routePattern: "/languages/{langId}/{action}/"
        );
    });
```

In such a way that Razor would map `/languages/{langId}/export` automatically to `Export.cshtml`. I am sure there's a way but so far it escapes me. Unfortunately, I can't make sense of the documentation regarding mapping a route to a folder.

If someone can point me in the correct direction, I will be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible with routing conventions.
Code below will add a suffix to certain routes based on the created route. But you can customize this to your need by changing the `.CombineTemplates`.

```
services.AddRazorPages(options => {
            var folders = new string[] { "/Languages" };
            for (int k = 0; k < folders.Length; k++)
            {
                options.Conventions.AddFolderRouteModelConvention(folders[k], model =>
                {
                    var selectorCount = model.Selectors.Count;
                    for (var i = 0; i < selectorCount; i++)
                    {
                        var selector = model.Selectors[i];
                        selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template = 
                        AttributeRouteModel.CombineTemplates(selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template, "{langid}/{action}");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```